# HP Elan Precision Touchpad becomes unresponsive after few minutes of use (Windows 10)

Tags: windows-10, laptop, touchpad, hp-pavilion

I bought an HP Pavilion 15 dk 0046tx Laptop with ELAN precision touchpad. The touchpad horribly starts lagging after few minutes of use.

Scrolling is misinterpreted as right click. Multi-finger gesture don't work.

I have tried the following:

- Updating the BIOS
- Updating ELAN Touchpad drivers from HP
- Updating Windows through windows update

None of that worked so far. The touchpad works fine for few minutes of booting in Windows 10, and works fine in Ubuntu, so I guess its not an hardware issue.

Comment: Did you contact HP support about the issue?

Comment: Yes, they suggested to update the bios and touchpad drivers which I did. They left the issue hanging.

Comment: If it is not too old, ask for a refund.

Comment: Did you install a custom touchpad driver in Linux, such as IMWheel or other? If you could tell us what driver version you have in Windows, it could help, because most of those drivers aren't so heavily customized by OEMs. I once managed to install a Dell driver set on a Toshiba laptop, and it worked a lot better than the one Toshiba offered for download on their support page... You could try to update yours via Snappy Driver Installer (https://sdi-tool.org/); choose to download indexes. The software offers to download drivers that are "older but better", and/or "newer". Could help.